# invoking bash using java servlet

Tags: java, shell

In my shell script, i'd like to use svn update command to update my svn repo on the server. 
But when I invoke the shell script manually, everything is fine. While when I invoke the shell script using Java servlet, the svn update command seems not executed. 
What is the matter with that?

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to invoke the command?

Comment: Probably the user that executes your Application Server (e.g. Tomcat, JBoss) doesn't have enough privileges to execute the script.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Thanks, you are right. I have to run the tomcat server at sudo mode

Comment: You're welcome. @hexafraction usually this kind of questions **don't need** any code at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the user that tries to execute the script doesn't have enough privileges. Make sure the user that executes the Application Server (Tomcat, JBoss) has enough privileges to execute your script as well.